# how to know feature contributions in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

in R I trained a model with good performance. It takes time to train, since it has over 200 predictors(features). Is there a way to get to know what features contributes most? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you're using the `randomForest` package, look at `varImpPlot` (variable importance plot), and the `importance` function, which extracts the importance values from a `randomForest` model object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is too vague as it stands since there can be any number of ways to determine variable importance based on the problem at hand. In any case, please have a look at what is available in the `caret` package here:

http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/varimp.html